# Adding new enum column to an existing table

Tags: mysql, enums, alter

I'm trying to add a `gender` column to my table with this query:

```
ALTER TABLE QRCodeUser ADD gender CHAR(1) enum('M','F') NOT NULL;
```

I get this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use  near 'enum('M','F') NOT NULL' at line 1

What's my mistake?

Comment: `CHAR(1)` is a type. `enum('M','F')` is also a type. A column can only have one type.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try this (you dont need to specify the size, `char(1)` ) :

```
ALTER TABLE QRCodeUser ADD gender  enum('M','F') NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it works ! But why did it not work my solution....I dont understand...

Comment: @dsharew what is 'M' and 'F' stand for?

Comment: It is part of the question; It seems for "Male" and "Female" though

Comment: I think this enum list in the answer may need to be updated for 2019 :laugh:

Comment: @AndrewSohn going to need to convert it to a varchar :P

Answer (score 6):

Correct usage of syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name  enum(`field1`,`field2`,...);
```

Comment: enum defines a set of values to be assigned to the column
a better example is
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name  enum(`value1`,`value2`,...,value_n);
can't define also CHAR(1) because ENUM os a type
mysql internally use int to represents ENUM 
it uses the ordinal positions of the value in the definition
so value1 is eq to 0
value2 is eq to 1 
and value_n is eq to n
HTH